# How to add additional value to option in a drop down and how to get that value when option is selected in angular js 1.x

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have the below code in jQuery. I want to know what is the equivalent code of above in Angular Js 1.x Versions?

```
<select id="select">
  <option value="1" data-foo="dogs">this</option>
  <option value="2" data-foo="cats">that</option>
  <option value="3" data-foo="gerbils">other</option>
</select>
```

```js
// JavaScript using jQuery
$(function() {
  $('select').change(function() {    
    var selected = $(this).find('option:selected');
    var extra = selected.data('foo'); 
  });
});

var sel = document.getElementById('select');
var selected = sel.options[sel.selectedIndex];
var extra = selected.getAttribute('data-foo');
```

Comment: this may help you understand about [Angular select](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select) using `ng-model`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use `jQuery` when you are using `angularjs`.

To get the selected value in dropdown, you need to model `select` with [**`ng-model`**](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModel) and then the value will be there on the fly. That's the beauty of `angularjs`.

Moreover, if you are interested to add options on fly, better use [**`ng-repeat`**](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat) to do that. And push in the array when you need to add another option. The option will be added to `select`. Another piece beauty of `angularjs`

Here

```js
angular.module('app',[]).controller('ctrl', function($scope){

 $scope.options = [{value : 1, attr: "dogs" },{value : 2, attr: "cats" },{value : 3, attr: "gerbils" }];
 
 $scope.data = $scope.options[0]
 $scope.select = 1;
 $scope.add = function(){
   $scope.options.push({value : $scope.options.length + 1, attr: 'option'})
 
 };
 
 $scope.getFoo = function(){
        
    $scope.data = $scope.options.find(o=> o.value == $scope.select)
 }
 
 
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app='app' ng-controller='ctrl'>
<select id="select" ng-model="select" ng-change="getFoo()">
  <option ng-repeat="option in options" value="{{option.value}}" data-foo="{{option.attr}}">{{option.attr}}</option>

</select>

<button ng-click="add()">Add option</button>
{{data.value}}
{{data.attr}}
 
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks,i have one doubt that is,using model name 'select'   i get only value of that option  how  will i get data-foo value of  selected option?

Comment: if you want `data-foo` for the selected tag. use this as value in options

Comment: like `value="{{option.attr}}"`

Comment: I mean i want to  show {{select}} // selected option value  at the same  time i want to show selected option   data-foo value.

Answer (score 0):

Add the value to the model that is provided as the data source for ng-repeat and set ng-model for dropdown .And get value of dropdown using ng-model.